# Converting a setText to a double

Tags: android

I need to convert the answer from the calculator into a string then to a double.

This is my code thus far:

```
final Button multiply =(Button)findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        final EditText num1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.carboninput);
        final EditText num2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.distanceinput);
        final TextView ans =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double n1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString());
                double n2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());

                ans.setText(String.valueOf(n1*n2));


            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need to make the

```
ans.setText(String.valueOf(n1*n2));
```

into a string that can be shown in the next idea then convert it to a double so the user can multiply the answer again.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want?

Comment: Double.parseDouble . Or you can store the last result in a global variable ..what's so tricky here ??

Comment: I need a button that acts like a counter but instead of being able to add +1 to ans.setText(String.valueOf(n1*n2)); everytime I press it I need to multiply it by two

Comment: Do you want to change the value in the `num1` and `num2` as well when you multiply the `ans` by 2?

Comment: Nope. I just need the ans.setText(String.valueOf(n1*n2)); to multiply itself when the button is clicked.